# VS 2013 Cordova CTP 3.1: Windows-AnyCPU fails to install with Error : DEP0730

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-cordova

I have upgraded to VS2013 Cordova CTP3.1 and now cannot install the app to Windows-AnyCPU.

The Cordova app builds successfully but then fails to deploy reporting the following error :-

```
Error   13  Error : DEP0730 : Registration of the application failed because no Developer License is installed on the target machine. Package Microsoft.WinJS.1.0_1.0.9866.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe with Windows Store origin cannot be sideloaded or installed using developer mode option. (0x80073cff)
```

The app successfully builds and deploys to Windows Phone 8, Windows Phone (Universal), Android and iOS.

I do have a valid development Licence until September this year and a C++ Windows App Store project successfully built, installed and ran on the PC.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this on Window10 Preview machine? There is a known issue with trying to build a Cordova app for Windows-AnyCPU on Windows10 Preview OS, as explained [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f62c3a67-3f17-4814-9cf4-258d9c654d70/developer-licence-not-found?forum=vssetup)